excel get sheet name from address
i am trying to get the full sheetname dynamically from the address with the below formula in another sheet. is there a better way ?
address : '[Airport - Daily Burn Rate_2024.05.08.xlsx]HQ 2024'!$A$1
result : 'HQ 2024'
my formula :
="'"&MID(TEXTAFTER(CELL("address";'HQ 2024'!A1);"]";1;0);1;
               FIND("~";SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(CELL("address";'HQ 2024'!A1);"]";1;0);"'";"~";1))
               )

PS if the sheename changes, i dont want my other formula connected to this sheet to be ruined...

Why have you not used something like this: ="'"&TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(CELL("address",'HQ 2024'!A1),"]"),"!")

@MayukhBhattacharya i dont know why :) thank you... pls post it as an answer...

Here is an alternative way, one could try using TEXTBEFORE() and TEXTAFTER():


="'"&TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(CELL("address",'HQ 2024'!A1),"]"),"!")


I use:
This in cell DA1 to get the sheet name:
MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1),1)+1,50)

uses the position of the "]", and then:
This to get a list of all the sheets between the firstone and lastone, as there are other sheets I do not want listed:
TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", FALSE,Firstsheet:Lastsheet!DA1),",")


thank you for the answer but filename returns #VALUE error in my excel, that's why i have to use address instead...

Did you put "filename" in quotes? or is the word different in your language? it is an argument to the cell() function.

although it show "filename" in the quote of the formula help, it returns error...

Well, I think you are making an error that you have not realized, what I posted works correctly.

there is nothing wrong with the syntax... check the video

I don't need to check the video - I have my working version :)

but most important for me that your formula does not work in my version (:

Why don't you use Formula Evaluation, which can be found in ribbon "Formulas", chapter "Formula Auditing", "Evaluate Formula", like in the following screenshot:

By evaluating step by step, you can see where it goes wrong.
Here, e.g. you can see that the problem is caused by the CELL("address";'HQ 2024'!A1) function, which returns the address of your cell, but not the content.

there is no problem actually, my formula is working... i wanted to search for a simplier formula...
